Multithreading vs multiprocessing in I/O bound processes
I was reading an article about concurrency in python and decided to try the code out in my local machine. If I understand it correctly then multithreading is supposed to be better at I/O bound processes than multiprocessing. However,when I run my test code I find that multiprocessing is about twice as fast for this piece of code. Could anyone help me with why this happens?
Multiprocessing code-
import requests
import multiprocessing
import time

session = None


def set_global_session():
    global session
    if not session:
        session = requests.Session()


def download_site(url):
    with session.get(url) as response:
        name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
        print(f"{name}:Read {len(response.content)} from {url}")


def download_all_sites(sites):
    with multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=set_global_session) as pool:
        pool.map(download_site, sites)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sites = [
        "https://www.jython.org",
        "http://olympus.realpython.org/dice",
    ] * 300
    start_time = time.time()
    download_all_sites(sites)
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"Downloaded {len(sites)} in {duration} seconds")

Multithreading code-
import concurrent.futures
import requests
import threading
import time


thread_local = threading.local()


def get_session():
    if not hasattr(thread_local, "session"):
        thread_local.session = requests.Session()
    return thread_local.session


def download_site(url):
    session = get_session()
    with session.get(url) as response:
        print(f"Read {len(response.content)} from {url}")


def download_all_sites(sites):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        executor.map(download_site, sites)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sites = [
        "https://www.jython.org",
        "http://olympus.realpython.org/dice",
    ] * 300
    start_time = time.time()
    download_all_sites(sites)
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"Downloaded {len(sites)} in {duration} seconds")


multiprocessing pays for 2 extra things:

serialization of arguments and return.
startup time (usually < 1 second)

on the other hand multiprocessing gives each process a new Global interpreter Lock (GIL) so tasks are truly executed in parallel, with no GIL contention. (IO is parallel with multithreading, but response construction and printing is sequential)

your arguments are relatively small, and you return None, this would matter more in a web server with a big shared state across workers.
the startup time is negligible compared to tasks time (1 vs 15 seconds).

multithreading is not necessarily faster or slower than multiprocessing, it depends on the task at hand, for example let's return the content, and reduce the tasks count to just 40 tasks, and you will see the difference.
10s  : multiprocessing, no return, 600 tasks
14s  : multithreading, no return, 600 tasks
3s   : asyncio with aiohttp, no return, 600 tasks

4.8s : multiprocessing, return the content, 40 tasks
1.7s : multithreading, return the content, 40 tasks
0.5s : asyncio with aiohttp, return the content, 40 tasks

timing is not consistent, take the numbers with a grain of salt

in short you need to use the correct tool for the task at hand, and for this specific taks a better tool would be asyncio with aiohttp so you don't even waste time on context switching between threads.
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

async def download_site(url, session):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            html = await response.text()
            print(f"Read {len(html)} from {url}")

async def download_all_sites(sites):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for site in sites:
            tasks.append(download_site(site, session))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sites = [
        "https://www.jython.org",
        "http://olympus.realpython.org/dice",
    ] * 300
    start_time = time.time()
    asyncio.run(download_all_sites(sites))
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"Downloaded {len(sites)} in {duration} seconds")

asyncio is faster because it is equivalent to 600 workers, it launches all requests before the first response arrives, and it only uses 1 thread, so it doesn't waste time context switching.

This variation on your code raises some interesting points:
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor
import time
import requests
from functools import partial
import os

def threading(session, site):
    try:
        with session.get(site) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
    except Exception:
        pass

def processing(site):
    global gsession
    try:
        with gsession.get(site) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
    except Exception:
        pass

def pinit(sess):
    global gsession
    gsession = sess

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sites = [
        "https://www.jython.org",
        "http://olympus.realpython.org/dice",
    ] * 300
    start = time.time()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(os.cpu_count()) as exe:
        with requests.Session() as session:
            exe.map(partial(threading, session), sites)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Multithreading duration = {end-start:.2f}s")
    start = time.time()
    with requests.Session() as sess:
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(initializer=pinit, initargs=(sess,)) as exe:
            exe.map(processing, sites)
        end = time.time()
        print(f"Multiprocessing duration = {end-start:.2f}s")

Output:
Multithreading duration = 4.33s
Multiprocessing duration = 4.60s

Observations:
Multithreading is marginally faster than multiprocessing in this case (where no values are returned and consequently avoids any serialisation).
The max thread count is set to os.cpu_count() That's because the ProcessPoolExecutor will (by default) use that value for the pool size whereas ThreadPoolExecutor defaults to min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4) In other words, if I didn't constrain the thread pool in this way, the number of threads would be 12 (Apple Silicon M2). In fact, if I do not constrain the number of threads, the multithreading duration is ~3.27s
Unless you only have one CPU (i.e., os.cpu_count() == 1) on your platform, the constant value of 5 used in your test is not realistic.
Summary:
For this pattern of execution, multithreading outperforms multiprocessing - as expected
